# Calling MATLAB functions in C++ unit test using MATLAB Engine API

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, cppunit

I have a C++ unit test where I need to call a Matlab member function of Matlab class(prototype) which returns an array of complex-doubles which is used as reference to assert against the return value of equivalent C++ implementation. I went through the documentation of the [engOpen Matlab API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/engopen.html). I am not sure how to get started with using this API in the CPP unit test, so a step by step procedure with an example to set this up would be helpful.